# How to insert a new line in strings in Android

Tags: android, string, enter

I'm creating an android application and within it there is a button that will send some information in an email, and I don't want to have everything all in one paragraph.

**Here's what my app is doing for the putExtra for the email's body:**

```
I am the first part of the info being emailed. I am the second part. I am the third part.
```

**Here's what I want it to do:**

```
I am the first part of the info being emailed.
I am the second part.

I am the third part.
```

How would I put a new line into a string or with the `putExtra` method to accomplish that?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Try using `System.getProperty("line.separator")` to get a new line.

Comment: Also, I learned putting \n within a string inserts a new line

Comment: @Jakar `System.getProperty("line.separator")` is platform independent and `\n` is not. But if you're developing android apps the platform is fixed and linux/android uses `\n` as newline char.
[wikipedia/Newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

Comment: @wischi, Good point. And `\r\n` is more cross-system-compatible I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) and is better for transferring data as a result. Such as if you send an email using `\n` to and it's read on a system that uses `\r\n`, you may lose lines, whereas in most cases if you pass `\r\n` to a system wanting just `\n`, it will compensate. I might be wrong here, and I don't have a source. This is just what I've gathered over time.

Answer (score 106):

Try:

```
String str = "my string \n my other string";
```

When printed you will get:

`my string`
`my other string`

Comment: This is not system independent. Some systems use \r\n for line breaks

Comment: @Gibolt This IS system independent. Android runs only on Linux based devices and therefore the \n is consistent among all devices.

Answer (score 28):

I would personally prefer using "**\n**". This just puts a line break in Linux or Android.

**For example,**

```
String str = "I am the first part of the info being emailed.\nI am the second part.\n\nI am the third part.";
```

**Output**

```
I am the first part of the info being emailed.
I am the second part.

I am the third part.
```

A more generalized way would be to use,

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

**For example,**

```
String str = "I am the first part of the info being emailed." + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "I am the second part." + System.getProperty("line.separator") + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "I am the third part.";
```

brings the same output as above. Here, the static `getProperty()` method of the `System` class can be used to get the "`line.seperator`" for the particular OS.

But this is not necessary at all, as the OS here is fixed, that is, **Android**. So, calling a method every time is a **heavy and unnecessary operation**.

Moreover, this also increases your code length and makes it look kind of messy. **A "\n" is sweet and simple.**

Comment: You have spaces after the newlines in your string that are not shown in the output, and the output has an extra blank line.

Comment: @MatthewRead Thanks, I have removed the spaces. But I do not see any extra blank line anywhere.

Answer (score 11):

I use `<br>` in a `CDATA` tag.
As an example, my strings.xml file contains an item like this:

```
<item><![CDATA[<b>My name is John</b><br>Nice to meet you]]></item>
```

and prints

```
My name is John
Nice to meet you
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add line break at runtime into a String from same string you are deriving the value then this Kotlin code works for me:

```
str = "<br>"+str?.replace("," , "</br><br>")+"</br>"
value = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(${skill_et_1}",Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
tv.text = value
```

Comment: You are using `val` as a variable here but `val` is a reserved keyword in kotlin.