# How do you set CR terminator in android when sending data as string?

Tags: android, eclipse, carriage-return, linefeed, medical

I am sending letter A (string letter = "A\n") on my android phone to a device. In matlab the code is set(s1,'Terminator', 'CR'). I would like to know how this is done from on an android phone. I want an enter after I sending letter A. Thanks for you answers in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer. "\n" is  new line feed, "\r" is carriage return. "\n" = 10 in decimal; and "\r" = 13 in decimal. so I want 13 in decimal for Carriage return, "\r" worked for me instead of "\n". (Look at the ASCII table closer :))

Comment: if you find this helpful, please vote the answer up so I can build my reputation on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
String num = String.valueOf(number);
String cr =  String.valueOf(number_cr);
String s = num + "\n" + cr;
```

or you can try something like:

```
String eol = System.getProperty("line.separator");  
String s = num + eol + cr;
```

See [How to insert a new line in strings in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379975/how-to-instert-a-new-line-in-strings-in-android) for more. Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried the two ways you suggested but it didnt work for me. String s to decimal 65 10 but I want 65 13 (13 is carriage return)

Comment: i am trying both the methods and they seems to work. Check it yourself. Run the code here: http://rextester.com/live/ZLN61101

Comment: You can first try to convert those integers to string using `String.valueOf(number)` and then use them

Comment: I have found the answer. "\n" is  new line feed, "\r" is carriage return. "\n" = 10; and "\r" = 13. so I want 13, "\r" worked for me instead of "\n"

Comment: Great. You can post that as a new answer. This would help those who would come to this thread in future. Thanks :)