# Cannot understand how to add new line only in xml

Tags: android, android-xml, android-resources

Please, explain me how can I add a new line in xml only (when I will use this string in program this must be single line)?

For example:

```
<string name="test">This
is
test
line</string>
```

But in program when I will use `getString(R.string.test);` it will load single string without some new line characters: `This is test line`.

I need this only for file formatting.

Comment: Should be '\n' See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693544/carriage-returns-line-breaks-with-n-in-strings-in-android

Comment: I need to understand how to split a long string in some strings in xml only. To I don't need in any actions in java code when I will use this string. When I will load this string resource all `new line` characters in xml must disappear.

Comment: Just I have fixed file string length (80 characters per string in code and xml files) and want format my long strings for better view.

Comment: Not clear on your ask. If `<string>This\nis\ntest\nline</string>` isn't what you are looking for, perhaps this is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862975/how-to-put-space-character-into-a-string-name-in-xml

Comment: Thanks! Just I think that if xml parses single spaces then it will parse `new line` characters too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to force a newline in the XML string just use '\n' (assuming your TextView is sized properly):

```
<string>This\nis\ntest\nline</string>
```

**Output**

This
is
test
line

See: [How to insert a new line in strings in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379975/how-to-insert-a-new-line-in-strings-in-android)

Otherwise you can inject in a blank space `&#032;` or `&#160;` for adjusting your string formatting.

See: [How to put space character into a string name in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862975/how-to-put-space-character-into-a-string-name-in-xml)