# newline ("\n") and tab ("\t") doesn't work when displaying String in TextView?

Tags: android, string, textview

The String is coming from an API response, when trying to display it on a `TextView`, `\n` and `\t` doesn't work. Here is the sample String:

*ECONOMY\nBooking purchased under this fare type: \n\n-\tis ALLOWED to do a flight change up to 48 hours prior to the scheduled departure time subject to a change fee chargeable per passenger per sector, plus any fare difference applicable.\n-\tis NOT ALLOWED to do a name change.\n-\tis capacity controlled and limited and hence, may not be available on all flights.\n-\tis always subject to our General Terms and Conditions of Carriage & Fee Schedule (if applicable). \n*

Comment: Display how? Please explain more and preferably show some code

Comment: your text is working when it is hardcoded in textView . show me your code.

Comment: string display same as given above,, i want to apply \n to new line and \t to space,, but those special character display in string

Comment: How are you displaying this? On what widget? `TextView`, `EditText`, etc?

Comment: string coming from API response, not hardcoded

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/31545857/5545429

Answer (score 1):

```
  String pureString = android.text.Html.fromHtml(fareRules).toString();
    String str1 = pureString.replace("[", "");
    str1 = str1.replace("]", "");
    str1 = str1.replace("\"", "");
    str1 = str1.replace("-", "");
    str1 = str1.replace("\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    str1 = str1.replace("\\t", getString(R.string.tab));
    ((TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.fare_rules)).setText(str1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
string = string.replace("\\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Comment: it's not working,, contain of \n is remove but output not get in new line

Answer (score 0):

use `<br />` inplace of `\n` .

An option could be to wrap it in CDATA:

```
<string name="yourtest"><![CDATA[first line, <br />second line]></string>
```